# Adding a CSS pseudo-element at the end of each non-explicit line break

Tags: css

I'm showing a bookcase on a webpage, using both `<img>` and `<div>` elements, with shelves separating each line of edges. Currently, I add these shelves programmatically : each time I detect that the position of a new edge if lower than the previous edge, I add a shelf in between.

[image: shelves]

However, this has the disadvantage that each time a user resizes the window, the shelves get messed up, with either books without shelves or shelves with too few books.

[image: messed up shelves]

I know how to use pseudo-elements but I can't find a way to use them to target only the first element of each row. Do I have any CSS-only options here?

```css
div.edge {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/25x150') no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.edge {
  margin-top: 15px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.shelf {
  height: 15px;
  background: url("https://media.freestocktextures.com/cache/25/a8/25a8e8f0073efa0592f685739ce3386b.jpg");
}
```

```html
<img class="edge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x200" />
<img class="edge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/15x300" />
<div class="edge">&nbsp;</div>
<img class="edge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x200" />
<img class="edge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/15x300" />
<div class="edge">&nbsp;</div>
<img class="edge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x200" />
<img class="edge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/15x300" />
<div class="edge">&nbsp;</div>
<img class="edge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x200" />
<img class="edge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/15x300" />
<div class="edge">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="shelf" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do it with only divs then it would be easy to consider pseudo elements:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom:15px;
}

.edge {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-size:0;
}

.edge::before {
  content: var(--i, url('https://via.placeholder.com/25x150'));
}

.edge::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 15px;
  background: url("https://media.freestocktextures.com/cache/25/a8/25a8e8f0073efa0592f685739ce3386b.jpg");
  left: -100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/20x200)"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/15x300)"></div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/20x200)"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/15x300)"></div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/20x200)"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/15x300)"></div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/20x200)"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/15x300)"></div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/20x200)"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/15x300)"></div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/20x200)"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/15x300)"></div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/20x200)"></div>
  <div class="edge" style="--i:url(https://via.placeholder.com/15x300)"></div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your for the answer. I'm not a big fan of CSS variables but it looks like it's the only way

Comment: @BrunoPérel you are not obliged to use CSS variables ;) I used them for simplicity. You can replace the :before and url trick with an img tag so you have the edge div and inside an img